# How I can pass images from activity A to activity B?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, imageview

I've created a list and when I click on any item I want to send images to another activity.

Here is the code :

```
 

    lv.onItemClickListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    if (position==0){
                        startActivity(Intent(this@HomeActivity,DisplayActivity::class.java).apply {
                            putExtra("v1",R.drawable.h2)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've put an empty `ImageView` in the `B` activity to receive the passed image.
What I should write in activity `B`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not trying to pass a Bitmap to the second activity, but you are passing the integer drawable resource id.
So, in the second activity try to read an `integer` from the intent.. something like this..

```
val intent:Intent=getIntent()
val image:Int= intent.getIntExtra("v1")
```

Comment: `val resourceId:Int= intent.getIntExtra("resourceid")` We like readable code ;-)

Comment: @blackapps who sets the extra name (v1) and pass a const resource id to another activity, will he care about the readability?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQLite? Because an image sometimes is too large, the best way is to save the image in SQLite and just pass the ID via intent. Then, read it back on the other activity.

Answer (score -1):

if you are try to pass drawable as bitmap pleas etry below code

```
/*** convert drawable to bit-map*****/

     val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.image_one
        )

/**************get byte array from bitmap ************/

      val bStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream)
            val byteArray: ByteArray = bStream.toByteArray()

/****************** pass byte array to next activity usign intent**********/

    val anotherIntent = Intent(this, anotherActivity::class.java)
            anotherIntent.putExtra("image", byteArray)
            startActivity(anotherIntent)

/************** get drawable in another activity ***************/

           val bmp: Bitmap
    
            val byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("image")
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray!!.size)
```

hope its work for you

Comment: eIntents have a 1 or 2 MB limit.  Passing images as a stream of bytes would be way too much for any non-trivial usage.  Instead they should either pass resource ids (for drawables) or URIs for image files.